# How do I get three equal columns using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure that the answer to this will be quite simple but I just can't figure it out. I have three tasks containing different list items and I want to arrange them in three equally sized columns using bootstrap. I've wrapped them in div class="col-md-4" but they continue to appear one below the other. I'm finding this really frustrating so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link type="text/CSS" rel="stylesheet" href="path to bootstrap.css file"/>
        <link type="text/CSS" rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css"/>

        <title>Getting Started</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="prerequisites">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h3>Task 1</h3>
                        <ol>
                            <li>Step 1</li>
                            <li>Step 2</li>
                            <li>Step 3</li>
                        </ol>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h3>Task 2</h3>
                        <ol>
                            <li>Step 1</li>
                            <li>Step 2</li>
                            <li>Step 3</li>
                            <li>Step 4</li>
                            <li>Step 5</li>
                        </ol>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h3>Task 3</h3>
                        <ol>
                            <li>Step 1</li>
                            <li>Step 2</li>
                            <li>Step 3</li>
                            <li>Step 4</li>
                        </ol>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you sure you're including Bootstrap properly? Your code works fine if it is: http://www.bootply.com/kDSgkOD09h. All I see in your example are CSS files.

Comment: Try using col-xs-4 it is possible your screen size is too small for md

Comment: Your href "path to bootstrap.css file" looks suspicious other than that looks fine

Comment: Is your browser large enough to use the `md` size?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I downloaded the bootstrap CSS file to our server and linked to it there. "path to bootstrap.css file" was meant just as a placeholder for the server path. I've switched to col-xs-4 and now the first two tasks are displayed next to each other. The third appears below them. Not sure why this is since the browser has a width of 1680.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure your doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and that

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

are in the head of your html page with the correct DOCTYPE.

if the issue still persists, i would start with checking that nothing inside Main.css is turning the floats off for your columns. nextly, check the browser window width. its must be greater than 969px if i am not mistaken. you can use col-sm-4 or col-xs-4 for smaller screen widths.

see the following fiddle sohwing that resizing the output window wide enough will get the three columns, but below that they appear on top of each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/521/

if it is still not working, post a link so we can see the source